# Minimum conection time in MIA from Buenos Aires?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, short-connections, american-airlines, mia

I'll be traveling to MIA from Buenos Aires with LATAM Airlines. I'll then take an AA flight to MCO. The connection time (if everything goes as scheduled) is 2 hours 16 minutes.

Is that enough time to make the connection from a LATAM flight that comes from Buenos Aires to an AA flight to MCO?

What happens if I don't make it because of a delay of the first flight or at immigration? Will it be treated as a no-show (meaning that I will lose the return flights as well)? Or is there some agreement between LATAM and AA?

We are 4 people traveling (3 of us with an ESTA and one Argentine with a regular tourist visa).

Any similar experiences?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Are both flights booked together on a single ticket, or did you purchase them separately? Do you plan to check luggage?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, 2:16 should be enough time for an International to Domestic connection at MIA.  But don't get distracted until you are at the gate for the MCO flight.

If you are able to, definitely use [Automated Passport Control](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/us-citizens/apc).  Once you complete the primary inspection at the kiosk, you *should* be directed to a different lane to complete the process.  LATAM should show a video on how the process works prior to landing.

The complication here is that you will arrive in the South Terminal, J usually, while your MCO flight will depart from the North Terminal D or maybe the Central Terminal E.  [Map here.](http://www.miami-airport.com/map-domestic-baggage-claim.asp)

If anyone in you party requires assistance, be sure to request it ahead of time.  If your MCO flight does depart from E, be sure make the TSA queue there.  Also, you will have to collect and recheck any luggage.

On any given day, American flies MIA-MCO 7 times.  If your inbound is late or CBP is backed up, AA will reaccommodate you on a later flight if they're booked on a single ticket.

Comment: Things must have changed a lot since I last was in MIA then... One could easily spend way over an hour in the queue at passport control in some cases, especially in the non-US queues, but that was before Automated Passport Control. Once you add time to disembark and get to passport control, reclaim luggage, re-check it, go to the other terminal, go through security, and get to your gate...